# Rspec - mock an activerecord table

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

Can I mock an activerecord table. Not a single model object.

I was looking something like that we do in cucumber.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I want to test a model for different queries.

Comment: I have a model Sub. and there are many methods which queries my model(Sub), firs one picks all records from the model. 2- all records which are created on particular date. 3- need grouped details by supplied columns. 4 - aggregate functions, etc

Comment: I'd go with dependency injection here. I don't have time to prepare a full answer right now. Maybe later. Or maybe someone will answer soon.

Comment: @sergio: Thanks! could you tell me, is it possible to mock or stub the table. Or need I go for something else?

Comment: I don't think "mock" is the term you want. Mocking is not for database tables. Perhaps you want test fixtures or factories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [rspec-activemodel-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-activemodel-mocks) is what you may be looking for.

It provides two helpers:

- `mock_model` to create a fake model (ex. `mock_model(Person, name: "Fred")`)
- `stub_model` to stub an existing one (ex. `stub_model(Person).as_new_record`)

Hope this still helps someone!